# How to filter a simple table/array in REACT

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter, react-bootstrap

im searching for a way to easily filter and maybe sort the following table. I tried filtering it with

```
      {data.getInteressentListing.edges.filter(node.name => node.name.includes('J')).map(({node}) => (
```

but that did not work. Also i need something like a search bar filtering not only the name. It should filter for all colums at the same time. Maybe you can give me some sugestions or a easy solution on this.

Thanks in advance

Daniel

Here is the code of my working simple table

```
import React from 'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table'

export const GET_POSTS = gql`
query   {
  getInteressentListing {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        Name
        Vorname
        Quelle
        Artikel
        Land
        Ort
        Tel
        Mobil
        EMail
        URL
        Whatsapp
        Telegram
        Notizen
        Geschlecht
      }
    }
  }
}
`;


const rowStyles = (post, canEdit) => canEdit(post)
  ? { cursor: 'pointer', }
  : {};

const PostViewer = ({ canEdit, onEdit }) => (
  <Query query={GET_POSTS}>
    {({ loading, data }) => !loading && (
      <Table >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Vorname</th>
            <th>Land</th>
            <th>Ort</th>
            <th>Tel.</th>
            <th>Mobil</th>
            <th>E-Mail</th>
            <th>Geschlecht</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.getInteressentListing.edges.map(({node}) => (
            <tr
              key={node.id}
              style={rowStyles(node, canEdit)}
              onClick={() => canEdit(node) && onEdit(node)}
            >
    <td> {node.Name} </td>
    <td> {node.Vorname} </td>
    <td> {node.Land} </td>
    <td> {node.Ort} </td>
    <td> {node.Tel} </td>
    <td> {node.Mobil} </td>
    <td> {node.EMail} </td>
    <td> {node.Geschlecht} </td>
             
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    )}
  </Query>
);
PostViewer.defaultProps = {
  canEdit: () => true,
  onEdit: () => null,
};

export default PostViewer;
```

That is the format my data looks like when i get it back. it has the node inside:

```
{
  "data": {
    "getInteressentListing": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "1294",
            "Name": "Felix",
            "Vorname": "Hase",
            "Quelle": "Facebook",
            "Artikel": "Briefe",
            "Land": "Deutschland",
            "Ort": "KiKaLand",
            "Tel": "+49 0256/659552",
            "Mobil": "01525659565",
            "EMail": "felix@kika.de",
            "URL": "www.felixderhase.de",
            "Whatsapp": true,
            "Telegram": false,
            "Notizen": "Läuft im Fernsehen",
            "Geschlecht": "Divers"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "1295",
            "Name": "Daniel",
            "Vorname": "Morgner",
            "Quelle": "eBay-Kleinanzeigen",
            "Artikel": "Omega",
            "Land": "Deutschland",
            "Ort": "Musterort",
            "Tel": "045692582",
            "Mobil": "015412,0",
            "EMail": "asdasd@web.de",
            "URL": "www.daniel.de",
            "Whatsapp": false,
            "Telegram": true,
            "Notizen": "asdasd",
            "Geschlecht": "Männlich"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "1296",
            "Name": "Muster",
            "Vorname": "Max",
            "Quelle": "eBay-Kleinanzeigen",
            "Artikel": "Musterartikel",
            "Land": "Musterland",
            "Ort": "Musterort",
            "Tel": "+49255225488",
            "Mobil": "+49536256",
            "EMail": "Max@mustermann.de",
            "URL": "www.mustermann.org",
            "Whatsapp": true,
            "Telegram": null,
            "Notizen": "Hat viele Muster",
            "Geschlecht": "Männlich"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "1297",
            "Name": "",
            "Vorname": "Peter",
            "Quelle": null,
            "Artikel": "Steine",
            "Land": "Deutschland",
            "Ort": "Musterort",
            "Tel": "07228562345",
            "Mobil": "01525654654654",
            "EMail": "peter-pan@web.de",
            "URL": "peter-walter.de",
            "Whatsapp": null,
            "Telegram": null,
            "Notizen": "Verkauft Steine",
            "Geschlecht": "Männlich"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "1298",
            "Name": "Jakob",
            "Vorname": "Hund",
            "Quelle": null,
            "Artikel": "Hundefutter",
            "Land": "Traumland",
            "Ort": "Bagdad",
            "Tel": "0152519188723",
            "Mobil": "025105153",
            "EMail": "jakob@web.de",
            "URL": null,
            "Whatsapp": null,
            "Telegram": true,
            "Notizen": "Ist ein Hund",
            "Geschlecht": "Männlich"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I request the data in my Query see code above

Comment: You can give a try with similar approach. You can check it out the demo like below. I did with VueJS you can follow the same approach with ReactJS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66685931/vue-searching-by-the-chosen-option-can-not-search-by-id-even-if-chosen/66686349#66686349

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but i can't figure out how to get it working properly. your code seems as simple as i wan't it to be in mine but i can't figure out how to get it working.

Comment: I created with pure React application with mock data with your mentioned key property and added filters too. Hopefully it will helps you. I added demo links too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: I tried with mock data in the state

```
this.state = {
  getInteressentListing: [
    {
      id: 1,
      Name: "Daniel",
      Vorname: "Daniel",
      Land: "Germany",
      Ort: "Deutschland",
      Tel: "9342423434",
      Mobil: "893434343434",
      EMail: "Daniel@gmail.com",
      Geschlecht: "Male"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      Name: "Morgner",
      Vorname: "Morgner",
      Land: "Germany",
      Ort: "Denmark",
      Tel: "92323232344",
      Mobil: "942343434344",
      EMail: "Morgner@gmail.com",
      Geschlecht: "Male"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      Name: "Jeba",
      Vorname: "Jeba",
      Land: "India",
      Ort: "Chennai",
      Tel: "8777788232323",
      Mobil: "923232323233",
      EMail: "jeba@gmail.com",
      Geschlecht: "Male"
    }
  ],
  selectedFilter: "id",
  filterByText: ""
};
```

Step 2: Input change input to set on `state`

```
inputChange = (event) => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  this.setState({ [name]: value });
};
```

Step 3: Written the filter function like below inside the `render` method

```
const filteredList = this.state.getInteressentListing.filter((item) => {
  if (this.state.selectedFilter && this.state.filterByText) {
    if (this.state.selectedFilter === "id") {
      return (
        item[this.state.selectedFilter] &&
        item[this.state.selectedFilter].toString() ===
          this.state.filterByText.toString()
      );
    } else {
      return (
        item[this.state.selectedFilter] &&
        item[this.state.selectedFilter]
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(this.state.filterByText.toLowerCase())
      );
    }
  } else {
    return item;
  }
});
```

Step 4: Finally the `html` template will be in render method like below,

```
<div className="App">
    <select
      name="selectedFilter"
      onChange={this.inputChange}
      value={this.state.selectedFilter}
    >
      <option disabled value="" required>
        Search by
      </option>
      <option value="id">Id</option>
      <option value="Name">Name</option>
      <option value="Vorname">Vorname</option>
      <option value="Land">Land</option>
      <option value="Ort">Ort</option>
      <option value="Tel">Tel</option>
      <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>
      <option value="EMail">EMail</option>
      <option value="Geschlecht">Geschlecht</option>
    </select>
    <input
      value={this.state.filterByText}
      name="filterByText"
      onChange={(e) => {
        this.inputChange(e);
      }}
      placeholder="Type here..."
    />
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Vorname</th>
          <th>Land</th>
          <th>Ort</th>
          <th>Tel.</th>
          <th>Mobil</th>
          <th>E-Mail</th>
          <th>Geschlecht</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {filteredList.map((node) => (
          <tr key={node.id}>
            <td> {node.Name} </td>
            <td> {node.Vorname} </td>
            <td> {node.Land} </td>
            <td> {node.Ort} </td>
            <td> {node.Tel} </td>
            <td> {node.Mobil} </td>
            <td> {node.EMail} </td>
            <td> {node.Geschlecht} </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
        {filteredList.length === 0 && (
          <tr>
            <td colSpan="8" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
              No Record Found
            </td>
          </tr>
        )}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-lewin-kpdsd)

Comment: Thank you very much. This example really helped me. Had to change the code a little bit but it works. As soon as i have finished (now i have to get working the edit entry code) i'll update with my finished code

Comment: @DanielMorgner it's my pleasure.

Comment: so i'm actually struggling getting my apollo data inside your code. filtering etc works with your static data. also i can't use my editor now. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/10/11/build-simple-web-app-with-express-react-graphql Thats the example code i was using so far

Comment: I added the answer to my Query to my post above. Hope you can help me to get this in your code. Thank you

Comment: @DanielMorgner I updated the code with your data in demo link. Kindly check and let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much that looks like it should, but the part i struggle the most is getting my Query into this.state instead of the demo data as the query is in the html code right now

Comment: So what i mean is that i use your code like

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          getInteressentListing: data,
          selectedFilter: "id",
          filterByText: ""
        };
      }

And start my querry to get -> data.
But i dont know how to get data defined and how to get my apollo request to be fully executed so that it shows my data. 
Maybe you can also see that the original code uses an edit feature. Is it possible to also implement this.

Comment: @DanielMorgner Can you refer the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53177346/react-apollo-graphql-search-filter

Comment: So you mean that i should not filter the results/data in my table. I should filter in my request. The idea of filtering before sounds good.

Comment: @DanielMorgner ya that is one kind of approach or you can go with https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/queries/#apply-the-usequery-hook approach. Using second approach you can do with client side filtering.

Comment: So i wanna say thank you again. This post has its answer. I've tried adding a filter and got a problem with the sysntax but i'll make an own post for that

Comment: @DanielMorgner Its my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

To search the entire row instead of a single field the user can actually do this based on the:

```js
const filteredList = this.state.getInteressentListing.filter((item) => {
  if (this.state.selectedFilter && this.state.filterByText) {
    const vv = Object.values(item);
    for (let i = 0; i < vv.length; i++) {
      vv[i] = vv[i] !== null ? vv[i].toString().toLowerCase() : vv[i];
    }

    return vv
      .join("")
      .includes(this.filterByText.toString().toLowerCase());
  } else {
    return item;
  }
});
```